# How to get labels from hclust result

Tags: r

let's say i have a dataset like this

```
dt<-data.frame(id=1:4,X=sample(4),Y=sample(4))
```

and then i try to make a  hierarchical clustering using the below code

```
dis<-dist(dt[,-1])
clusters <- hclust(dis)
plot(clusters)
```

and it works well

[image]

The point is when i ask for

```
clusters$labels
```

it gives me `NULL`, meanwhile i expect to see the label of indivisuals **in order** like

```
1, 4, 2, 3
```

**it is important to have them with the order that they are added in plot**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cluster$order` rather than labels if you happened to not have assigned the labels.

Infact you can see all the contents by using function called `summary`

```
clusters <- hclust(dis)
plot(clusters)
summary(clusters)
clusters$order
```

You can compare with the plot i received at my end, it is offcourse little different than yours

**My outcome:**

```
> clusters$order
[1] 4 1 2 3
```

Content of **summary** command:

```
> summary(clusters)
            Length Class  Mode     
merge       6      -none- numeric  
height      3      -none- numeric  
order       4      -none- numeric  
labels      0      -none- NULL     
method      1      -none- character
call        2      -none- call     
dist.method 1      -none- character
```

You can observe that since there is null value against labels, hence you are not getting the labels. To receive the labels you need to assign them first using `clusters$labels <- c("A","B","C","D")` or you can assign with the rownames, once your labels are assigned you will no longer see the numbers you will able to see the names/labels.

In my case I have not assigned any name hence receiving the numbers instead.

You can put the labels in the plot function itself as well.

From the documentation `?hclust`

> labels
>   A character vector of labels for the leaves of the tree. By
>   default the row names or row numbers of the original data are used. If
>   labels = FALSE no labels at all are plotted.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code:

```
# your data, I changed the id to characters to make it more clear
set.seed(1234) # for reproducibility
dt<-data.frame(id=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),X=sample(4),Y=sample(4))
dt

# your code, no labels    
dis<-dist(dt[,-1])
clusters <- hclust(dis)
clusters$labels

# add labels, plot and check labels
clusters$labels <- dt$id
plot(clusters)

## labels in the order plotted
clusters$labels[clusters$order]
## [1] A D B C
## Levels: A B C D
```

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you use rownames(...) to ensure your data has labels

```
> rownames(dt) <- dt$id
> dt
id X Y
1  1 2 1
2  2 4 3
3  3 1 2
4  4 3 4
> dis<-dist(dt[,-1])
> clusters <- hclust(dis)
> str(clusters)
List of 7
$ merge      : int [1:3, 1:2] -1 -2 1 -3 -4 2
$ height     : num [1:3] 1.41 1.41 3.16
$ order      : int [1:4] 1 3 2 4
$ labels     : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
$ method     : chr "complete"
$ call       : language hclust(d = dis)
$ dist.method: chr "euclidean"
- attr(*, "class")= chr "hclust"
>
```