# Labels on Tanglegram not working (dendextend)

Tags: r, label, dendextend

I tried several times to put the labels on the tanglegram (package dendextend) but my labels (etic) not working, they also work on a simple plot.
Which command should I use?

```
> dati<-read.table("moto.txt",header=T)
> dat<-dati[,-1:-3] #I delete the first three columns because they are 
    qualitative variables (motorcycle brand and model)
> etic<-read.table("moto.txt",header=T)[,2] #my labels (motorcycle model)
> etic
[1] R1200GS AfricaT V-Strom Scrambl MT-07   Z650    Tracer  Multist CB500X  
    Iron883 CMX500  Vulcan  Supers  CBR-RR  GSX-R  
> sdx<-scale(dat)
> d<-dist(sdx)#I assign the matrix of distances to "d"
> library (dendextend)
> hc1<-hclust(d,method="complete")
> hs1<-hclust(d,method="single")
> tanglegram(hc1,hs1, labels=etic)
Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) : 
 'labels' is supplied and not 'at'
  Inoltre: Warning messages:
  1: In plot.window(...) : parametro grafico "labels" non valido
  2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : parametro grafico "labels" non valido

> tanglegram(hc1,hs1) #tanglegram work but without labels
```

Comment: Would using as.character on etic solve the issue? If not then please create a fully reproducible ecample and I'll have a look.

Comment: as.character don't work. take a look at all the commands I used (i edited it).

Comment: Your code is not replicable.

Please read first the two following guides on how a good question should be written, this will help to ensure that you will get the assistance you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated

Answer (score 0):

There is no argument called "labels" in the function. You are supposed to update the labels of your dendrogram and supply that to the tanglegram.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you do not have labels assigned. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638810/how-to-get-labels-from-hclust-result) answer for a more comprehensive explanation, but here is a simple solution

```
#run hclust()    
my.hclust<-hclust(distance,method="ward.D2") 

#check the summary. If 'labels' says 'NULL' you need to assign them
summary(my.hclust)
            Length Class  Mode     
merge       94     -none- numeric  
height      47     -none- numeric  
order       48     -none- numeric  
labels       0     -none- NULL     
method       1     -none- character
call         3     -none- call     
dist.method  1     -none- character

#they can easily be assigned from the original dataframe using

my.hclust$labels <- mydf$mylabels
```

Your labels should now be shown when you plot using `tanglegram()`